# How to read a binary file data and store it into multiple vectors in C++?

Tags: vector, binary

I have a program which reads data from text file(contains 3 columns of data, columns 1&2 are integers and the 3rd is double) and stores it into 3 vectors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
main()
{
vector<int>a,b;
vector<double>c;
int a1,b1;
double c1;
ifstream fin("<filename>.txt",ios::in | ios::binary);
if(fin.is_open()){
while(!fin.eof())
{
 fin>> a1 >> b1 >> c1;
if(fin){
a.push_back(a1);
b.push_back(b1);
c.push_back(c1);
}
 }
}
fin.close();
}
```

Can somebody help me how to store data into the same 3 vectors if it is a **binary** file instead of a text file

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
fin>> a1 >> b1 >> c1;
```

you should use this for the normal binary files (no separator between values):

```
fin.read((char*)&a1, sizeof a1);
fin.read((char*)&b1, sizeof b1);
fin.read((char*)&c1, sizeof c1);
```

the `>>` operator does not work on binary files like you intend.

if you have a separator between the values you must read it too:

```
char buffer[LENGTH_OF_SEPARATOR];

fin.read((char*)&a1, sizeof a1);
fin.read(buffer, sizeof buffer);
fin.read((char*)&b1, sizeof b1);
fin.read(buffer, sizeof buffer);
fin.read((char*)&c1, sizeof c1);
```

Comment: Works for single column data transfer to a single vector. The data file is :
" column1<space>column2<space>column3".

Comment: do you have 1 char between the values in a binary file or do you have the ascii values for `<space>` between them? why? what is between column3 and the next column1 value?

Comment: I generated the values and stored it in the above format in MATLAB and then used MATLAB function "fwrite" to convert it into binary. So there is nothing after column3 and the next value in column1.

Comment: Ok. I've re modified the code to write in binary format. Tell me if the writing format is ok for it to be read in binary format with your code above.
`char buffer[]={" "};
ofstream fout("<filename>".bin,ios::out | ios::binary);
if(fout.is_open())
{

        if(fout)
        {
        fout.write((char *)&a, sizeof a);
        fout.write(buffer, sizeof buffer);
        fout.write((char *)&b, sizeof b);
        fout.write(buffer, sizeof buffer);
        fout.write((char *)&c, sizeof c);
        }
}

fout.close();`

Comment: i don't think so, `char buffer[]={" "};` makes the variable `buffer` to be an array of 2 chars, not only 1, so it will read 2 bytes. If there is only 1 byte between the values, you should do `char buffer[1];`.